# Cannot link against new API function

Tags: c, glib, dynamic-linking

I'm trying to add a new function to libsoup. I've gotten libsoup itself to compile correctly with my new function in it; I've also added the function prototype to the relevant header file. However, when trying to compile a test program against the local `so`, the linker complains that the reference to my new function is undefined. Checking with `objdump -T`, I can see that the function is there in the library, but not when checking with `nm -C -D`. Even if I globalize the symbol using `objcopy`, `nm` still can't see it.

I've also already tried adding `__attribute__((visibility("default")))`, but it doesn't seem to help.

I use this compiler invocation for my test program:

```
gcc -o test -I. -I $prefix/include/glib-2.0/ -I $prefix/lib/glib-2.0/include/ -L libsoup/.libs/ test.c -lsoup-2.4
```

Comment: Could you give us the exact parameters you use to link and compile the library?

Comment: I've added my compiler invocation, thanks.

Comment: Have you fixed the problem? If so, please answer the question and close this question.

Comment: No, I have not fixed the problem. Why did you think so?

Comment: Do you also have the standard libsoup installed on your system?

Comment: I think you should put your `-o` option and its arguments and the source code, at the last and try. Also could you show us how you compiled the `so` file?

Comment: I compiled the so file using the build system from libsoup (although built against the glib from my prefix). Putting the `-o` option at the end doesn't seem to help. Moving the `-l` option before target and source doesn't help, either. I do not have any libsoup installed in my system, as far as I can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that there is a `libsoup/libsoup-2.4.sym` file listing all the exported symbols in the repository. After adding my new function name to that file, I had to `rm libsoup/libsoup-2.4.la` and run `make` again, which resulted in my new function being available for use in my test program.